# How to get a string from a UITextField?

Tags: iphone, string, sdk, nsstring, uitextfield

How would I go about getting a string from a UITextField in the iPhone SDK? I'm trying to insert it into another concatenated string.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This should do it:

```
NSString *myString = myTextField.text;
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked! I know it's really simple, but I was doing something wrong before...

Answer (score 0):

```
lblAns.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",[[txtField1 text] intValue] + [[txtField2 text] intValue]];
```

you can do addition of two textboxs value like this...

Comment: At first assign all values into variables and perform addition. After that print the value

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *s = textfield.text;

yourString = [yourString appendString:s];
```

Answer (score 0):

for Swift 3.0

place these lines where you need

let yourString: String = ""

yourString = textField.text

Actually text attribute of textField provide the value to String.